# Plot Timeseries Data where the hourly variations are values in different columns

Tags: python, r, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a DataFrame as shown below. The Columns 0:00, 1:00.. till 24:00 represents the hours. How can I plot the hourly variation of both Items 'foo' and 'bar' for all the dates?

```
Date        Item  0:00   1:00  2:00  3:00  4:00  5:00  6:00 

1/1/2022    foo   2      3    4       1      5     1.5   2.5 
1/2/2022    foo   1.5    1    3       2      2.5   6     4
1/3/2022    foo   1      2    3       1      2     5     4
1/4/2022    foo   2      1    3       4      1     2.4   3
1/1/2022    bar   3      1    0       1.5    5     1.5   2.5
1/2/2022    bar   2.5    4    3       1      2.5   0     1
1/3/2022    bar   1      2    1       1      2     1.5   4
1/4/2022    bar   2      1    3       2      1     2.5   3
```

I tried the following

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df,row='Item',col='Date')
g.map(sns.#someplot,) # within map not sure what plot should I use and how to represent x axis as the columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need bars with separate plots for `Item`s use:

```
df1 = df.melt(['Date','Item'])
g = sns.FacetGrid(df1, row='Item', col="Date")
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x="variable", y="value")
```

Or if need both `Items` in one graph use:

```
df1 = df.melt(['Date','Item'])
g = sns.FacetGrid(df1, col="Date")
g.map_dataframe(sns.barplot, x="variable", y="value", hue="Item")
```

Answer (score 1):

With R and `ggplot2`, you have to pivot to long format for plotting.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date, Item), names_to = "time", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(time = ymd_hm(paste("0000-01-01",time, sep = " "))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Date)) +
  scale_x_datetime( breaks=date_breaks("60 min"), labels = date_format("%H:%M")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=8, angle = 90),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=8),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10)) +
  facet_grid(~Item, scale='free_x')
```

[image]

Another option if you want both series on the same plot.

```
library(tidyverse) 

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date, Item), names_to = "time", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(paste(ok$Date, ok$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value, colour = Item, group = Item)) +
  geom_line()
```

*Note: Since it is just a sample of the data, there are time gaps, hence the sharp angles.

[image]

Or if you want them separate, then you can `facet` the plot (also using bar for another alternative).

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date, Item), names_to = "time", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  mutate(time = as.POSIXct(paste(ok$Date, ok$time), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(colour = Item, fill = Item)) +
  facet_grid(~Item, scale='free_x')
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("1/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "1/3/2022", "1/4/2022", 
"1/1/2022", "1/2/2022", "1/3/2022", "1/4/2022"), Item = c("foo", 
"foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"), `0:00` = c(2, 
1.5, 1, 2, 3, 2.5, 1, 2), `1:00` = c(3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 1L), `2:00` = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L), `3:00` = c(1, 
2, 1, 4, 1.5, 1, 1, 2), `4:00` = c(5, 2.5, 2, 1, 5, 2.5, 2, 1
), `5:00` = c(1.5, 6, 5, 2.4, 1.5, 0, 1.5, 2.5), `6:00` = c(2.5, 
4, 4, 3, 2.5, 1, 4, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

In R just use `matplot`, no need for data wrangling beforehand.

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2)); by(df[3:9], df$Item, \(x) matplot(t(x), type='l'))
```

Or, more publishable:

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
by(df, df$Item, \(x) {
  matplot(t(x[1:4, 3:9]), type='l', main=el(x$Item), xaxt='n', xlab='t', ylab='y')
  axis(1, axTicks(1), colnames(df)[3:9])
  legend('topleft', leg=x$Date, col=seq_len(nrow(x)), lty=seq_len(nrow(x)), 
         cex=.8, ncol=2)
  })
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
df <- read.table(text="
                 Date Item 0:00 1:00 2:00 3:00 4:00 5:00 6:00
1 1/1/2022  foo  2.0    3    4  1.0  5.0  1.5  2.5
2 1/2/2022  foo  1.5    1    3  2.0  2.5  6.0  4.0
3 1/3/2022  foo  1.0    2    3  1.0  2.0  5.0  4.0
4 1/4/2022  foo  2.0    1    3  4.0  1.0  2.4  3.0
5 1/1/2022  bar  3.0    1    0  1.5  5.0  1.5  2.5
6 1/2/2022  bar  2.5    4    3  1.0  2.5  0.0  1.0
7 1/3/2022  bar  1.0    2    1  1.0  2.0  1.5  4.0
8 1/4/2022  bar  2.0    1    3  2.0  1.0  2.5  3.0
           ", check.names=F)
```